# "Closed $\mathscr{V}$-modules are uniquely (co)tensored $\mathscr{V}$-categories": shouldn't we assume they are also "mixed monoidal"?

Tags: ct.category-theory, monoidal-categories, symmetric-monoidal-categories

$\newcommand{\M}{\mathcal{M}}\newcommand{\V}{\mathscr{V}}\newcommand{\hom}{\mathsf{hom}}$Throughout this post, $\V$ refers to some "cosmos", where I borrow the word "cosmos" from Peter May and take it to mean:

> A bicomplete closed symmetric monoidal category with monoidal product $\otimes$ and monoidal unit $\ast$.

I will let $\alpha,\lambda,\rho$ denote the natural isomorphisms $(-)\otimes((-)\otimes(-))\cong((-)\otimes(-))\otimes(-):\V^3\to\V,\,\ast\otimes(-)\cong\mathrm{Id}:\V\to\V,\,(-)\otimes\ast\cong\mathrm{Id}:\V\to\V$ respectively (this is the notation of Mac Lane).

---

The below is just definitions and context.

In Riehl's Categorical Homotopy Theory, we have definition $10.1.3$:

> A closed $\V$-module $\M$ consists of a two-variable adjunction $(\odot,\pitchfork,\hom):\V\times\M\to\M$ and natural isomorphisms: $$\begin{align}\alpha_{\odot}:((-)\otimes(-))\odot(-)&\cong(-)\odot((-)\odot(-)):\V\times\V\times\M\to\M\\\lambda_{\odot}:\ast\odot(-)&\cong\mathrm{Id}:\M\to\M\end{align}$$

She claims (leaving it as an exercise) that a closed $\V$-module $\M$ is "uniquely" a tensored and cotensored enriched $\V$-category where the tensor-cotensor-hom adjunction descends to the given two-variable adjunction in $\odot,\pitchfork,\hom$. I found this statement a bit woolly, since there is no good notion (to my knowledge) of "equivalent identifications" $\M\sim(\underline{\M})_0$. I took it to mean, if you choose the internal homs $\underline{\M}$ to be given by $\hom$ and expect $\odot,\pitchfork$ to make $\underline{\M}$ a tensored and cotensored $\V$-category, then there is only one way in which the identity arrows and composition arrows (for the enriched category structure) can be defined.

So I decided to instead focus on finding the "obvious" or "canonical" enrichment of $\M$. As is often the case, there seems to be only one possible thing you could write down for this:

- The objects $\underline{\M}(m,n)\in\V$ are to be $\hom(m,n)$
- The identities $\mathrm{id}_x:\ast\to\underline{\M}(x,x)=\hom(x,x)$ are the adjuncts of $\lambda_{\odot}:\ast\odot x\to x$
- The compositions $\circ:\hom(b,c)\otimes\hom(a,b)\to\hom(a,c)$ are the adjuncts of: $$(\hom(b,c)\otimes\hom(a,b))\odot a\overset{\alpha_{\odot}}{\longrightarrow}\hom(b,c)\odot(\hom(a,b)\odot a)\to\hom(b,c)\odot b\to c$$Where the latter arrows are counit arrows.

Hopefully the reader agrees these are the natural definitions. I am quite pedantic about this sort of thing, so I decided to check that the coherence diagrams that must be satisfied for any enriched category are indeed satisfied, though it felt obvious. And after that preamble, here is the crux of the question:

---

I believe Riehl made an omission. Throughout the book, the coherence diagrams and coherence theorems for monoidal categories were swept under the rug of referring to CWM - which is fine - but here is an instance where I think it's important we be explicit about what, exactly, we assume of our monoidal structures. Specifically, I was surprised to discover that it was **necessary** that the following diagrams be assumed to always commute:

$$\begin{align}(a\otimes(b\otimes c))&\odot m\overset{\alpha\odot 1}{\longrightarrow}((a\otimes b)\otimes c)\odot m\overset{\alpha_{\odot}}{\longrightarrow}&(a\otimes b)\odot(c\odot m)\\\alpha_{\odot}&\downarrow&\downarrow\alpha_{\odot}\\&a\odot((b\otimes c)\odot m)\overset{1\odot\alpha_\odot}{\longrightarrow}&a\odot(b\odot(c\odot m)))\end{align}$$

And: $$\begin{align}(\alpha\otimes\ast)&\odot m\overset{\alpha_{\odot}}{\longrightarrow}&a\odot(\ast\odot m)\\\rho\odot1&\downarrow&\downarrow1\odot\lambda_{\odot}\\&a\odot m=&a\odot m\end{align}$$

In order for the obvious definition to actually be a definition of an enriched category. These seem like strong additional assumptions on our closed module $\M$.

These very strongly resemble the defining coherence diagrams for a monoidal category (the pentagon and triangle diagrams). The only difference is that two products appear: let me call this "mixed monoidal" (considering this separately from the adjunctions that make up a closed module). I have a few related questions:

- Has this kind of "mixed monoidal" structure been studied? Does it have a name?
- Under what conditions does a closed $\V$-module satisfy these "mixed monoidal" coherence diagrams? (I am here assuming that they don't always follow. If they do, then I'll be embarrassed for wasting my time on this question...)
- Going out on a limb, I also ask: is there a mixed monoidal coherence theorem analogous to the monoidal coherence theorem? That is, do 'all diagrams commute'?

Comment: If I understand right, your "mixed monoidal" structure is what's usually called a "module category" structure (e.g. S2.3 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0111139)). Certainly a V-module should be assumed to be a module category over V. Not sure if this fact is meant to follow from the rest of the definition.

Comment: @NoahSnyder I’d guess that, since the author of that paper kept the other coherences as part of the definition, these don’t follow trivially. Thank you very much! I will read this paper. I reckon Riehl needs to assume $(\mathcal{M},\odot)$ is also a $\mathscr{V}$-module for the rest to make sense.